# Como posso converter uma string em numero inteiro em Jacascript

Tags: javascript

Oi Boa tarde estou aprendendo a programar em js na verdade sou bastante novo no assunto.
estou tentando resolver um exercício mas a resposta não esta saindo certo. não estou conseginto convrrter a resposta. acredito que fiz tudo certo. Alquem pode me ajudar?

## Sistema de multas

Velocidade do Carro:  Km Hora

```
    <div id="res">

    </div> 

    <script>

        function calcular(){
            var txtv = window.document.querySelector('Input#txtvel')
            var res = window.document.querySelector('div#res')
            var vel = parseInt(txtv.value)
            res.innerHTML=  'Sua velocidade é ${vel} Km Hora'

        }
    </script>
```

**texto em negrito**

Comment: Para que `${vel}` funcione, vc precisa usar template string  (descrita no link indicado acima no box azul)

Comment: Jacascript ????

Comment: @Danizavtz javascript piorado?